# How to insert multiple inputs into the same row that group by the same data

Tags: php, sql

I have a system that records all the user's purchases.
In my system, I have a table called **purchase_item**.

The table **purchase_item** looks like this

| id | order_id | product_name |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 | iphoneX |
| 2 | 10001 | ipnone 12 Pro |
| 3 | 10001 | ipad |
| 4 | 10002 | Apple pen |
| 5 | 10002 | Airpods |
| 6 | 10002 | Iphone 12 Pro Max |

This is my query to insert the data above

```
$osql = "INSERT INTO `purchase_items`(`order_id`, `product_name`) VALUES ('$order_id',`$product_name` )";
```

Now i created another table(**receipt_table**) that i want to insert  the above data in group. Anyone knows how can i do it?

what I want is the output of my table to look like this:

| id | order_id |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 10001 |
| 2 | 10002 |

I want to group my data by using "INSERT INTO". Anyone knows how can i do that?

Answer (score 0):

The way to retrieve the last inserted id in MySQL is `$mysqli->insert_id`.

```
$mysqli = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$osql = "INSERT INTO `purchase_items`(`order_id`, `product_name`) VALUES (?, ?)";
$stmt = $mysqli->prepare($osql);
$stmt->bind_param("is", $order_id, $product_name);
$stmt->execute();

$id = $mysqli->insert_id;
$rsql = "INSERT INTO receipt_table (order_id) VALUES (?)";
$stmt = $conn->prepare($rsql);
$stmt->bind_param("i", $id);
$stmt->execute();
```

https://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.insert-id.php
https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_prepared_statements.asp

Answer (score 0):

Without knowing what sql dialect you use, but in **sql server** we could do like this:

```
INSERT INTO receipt_table(id, order_id)
select id, order_id
from purchase_items
group by id, order_id
```

Answer (score 0):

```php
<?php
$purchased_item = [
  [10001, "iPhoneX"],
  [10001, "iPhone 12 Pro"],
  [10001, "iPad"],
  [10002, "Apple Pen"],
  [10002, "Airpods"],
  [10002, "iPhone 12 Pro Max"]
];

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root"; //your user name
$password = ""; // your password here
$dbname = "myDB"; // database name

$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

$osql = "INSERT INTO `purchase_items`(`order_id`, `product_name`) VALUES (?,? )";
$ostmt = $conn->prepare($osql);
$isql = "INSERT INTO reciept_table(`id`, `order_id`) VALUES (?, ?)";
$istmt = $conn->prepare($isql);

$lastId = null; // to check id is entered or not
foreach ($purchased_item as $value) {
  $ostmt->bind_param("is", $value[0], $value[1]);
  $ostmt->execute();
  if ($lastId != $value[0]){
    $istmt->bind_param("i", $value[0]);
    $istmt->execute();
  }
  $lastId = $vlaue[0];
}
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

you can simple use a sql to insert grouped data.and I guess that receipt_table  id is an auto_incremnt id.

```sql
insert into 
    receipt_table(order_id)
    select order_id from purchase_items 
    group by order_id;
```